# ScrollTop to follow bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, element, scrolltop

I'd like my website to follow the content coming out of external source, which is loaded over time

I've tried to use

`chatContainer.scrollTop = chatContainer.scrollHeight;`

as my chatContainer is where the content is loaded, but it doesn't work as it should, could you give me some help with that? How to make a website follow the real-time rendered content with the view?

Comment: i dont get what are you asking

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you add more content dynamically, just call the following on the container element.

```js
const container = document.querySelector("#container");
container.scrollTop = container.scrollHeight;
```

Ensure you're calling this on the container that can scroll.

If you're using jQuery, it's quite simple and it can be animated.

```js
$("#container").animate({ scrollTop: $("#container")[0].scrollHeight }, 100);
```

Note that when you call `$("#container")[0].scrollHeight`, you are specifying that you want the scrollHeight of the first match as a document element (rather than a jQuery selector). It's the equivalent of doing `document.querySelector("#container")`. The 100 at the end is the number of milliseconds the animation should take.

There is no need for the MutationObserver. You don't need an interval either. You just need to run one of the above functions whenever you add content to the page (like a new message). Make sure to run it after the content is added or it won't work.

Edit: If you're not sure, open your browser's element inspector. Click on the node in the list that you want to scroll and run the following code `$0.scrollTop = $0.scrollHeight;`. If it doesn't work, then you're selecting the wrong element OR you haven't set your container heights correctly.

Here's an example

```js
let count = 0;

setInterval(function(){
    document.querySelector("#conversation").innerHTML += `<div class="message">Message ${count}</div>`;
    document.querySelector("#container").scrollTop = document.querySelector("#container").scrollHeight;
    count++;
}, 1000);
```

```css
html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; overflow: hidden; }

#container { width: 100%; max-height: 100%; border: 1px solid black; overflow-y:auto; }

.message { width: 100%; background-color: green; min-height: 100px; border-bottom: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="conversation">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I felt the need to respond since there are some information colliding with my answer. First of all you are not in the position to know if there's control on when you added content to the container since it could be a process belonging to a different component while you have control only on the container by definition (thus `MutationObserver`). Then the setInterval was just a way to demo an example with content dynamically added. Plus I really wished you had a live snippet as well because despite what lots of people says the `container.scrollTop = container.scrollHeight;` doesn't work actually

Comment: @DiegoD It absolutely does work. I've used it numerous times over the last decade. Secondly, if the OP doesn't have control over it, then it probably means it's content in an iframe, which means the MutationObserver won't work anyway. If you need an example so you learn how it works, I added one to the post.

Comment: @DiegoD furthermore, I'm not sure if you're aware but your scrollIntoView will scroll all viewports, not just the chat container. That means if your actual page has more on it and the chat is just a sidebar, it will still scroll to it even if the user is trying to view content lower on the page.

Comment: yes indeed it's working now. Thanks for the update. I tried to use that strategy before inside my frame and was not working as expected that's why I did that comment. I also modified my answer to remove that warning.

Comment: in relation to the latest comment instead, yes I was aware of some glitches.. that's why in the end I further improved the answer performing that call over the `:last-child` of the target and why I also changed the arguments passed so that its behaviour didn't affect the main window unless the target container isn't currently visible in the main viewport plus now its transition is `smooth`

Comment: @DiegoD I recommend running the snippet you posted and then scrolling the snippet sample out of view on the stackoverflow page to see the problem.

Comment: yes I did .. and that's what I was trying to achieve also. Shouldn't be a correct behaviour moving the whole viewport so that the target is visible? ok maybe I'm not in the position to take that decision that maybe it's arbitrary

Comment: So, basically what Zei said, is exactly how it was explained in the video I was learning from, and it's built exactly the same way, and it's working in the creator app, but it doesn't in my app

Comment: @codemeal Pay close attention to the way I set maximum heights for the containers and even the html and body. If your container isn't creating a scroll bar it won't work. You shouldn't need to touch the html and body if there are other containers between the chat container and those nodes.

Comment: @codemeal you should try and make use of your browser's element inspector. Find your container element in the inspector. Run the `$0.scrollTop = $0.scrollHeight;` piece of code. If nothing happens, look at the parent and see if there is a height set. My recommendation is to set the height to a pixel height (maybe like 400px) and try running that snippet on the container you are expecting to scroll. Keep fiddling with it until it moves and then you know which elements you need to set heights on to make it work.

Comment: @Zei so i've checked it with the $0.scrollTop = $0.scrollHeight; and it works, also i've changed the height property of #chat_container to a max-height and set it to 100%, and it still looks like it doesn't do what I would like it to, also does it matter if the scrollbar is set to display: none?

Comment: @codemeal the scroll bar should be hidden using `overflow: hidden;`. It will work even if the scrollbar is hidden. Keep in mind `max-height: 100%;` is the size of the parent element. I used it because I wanted it to take up the whole sample container on stackoverflow. If the parent element doesn't have a height set, then it will be the size of the next parent and that continues all the way up to the html tag. Try `height: 500px` and see if it works. Or even `height: 100%` on the `#chat-container` and then set an actual height on its parent.

Comment: @Zei i've set the parent height from 100vh to 500px and then chat_container to 100% but it doesn't change anything in my case, I'll drop the css code in case something is wrong here and im just blind to it

Comment: #app {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 500px;
  background: #343541;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#chat_container {
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;

  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;

  padding-bottom: 20px;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

/* hides scrollbar */
#chat_container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

Comment: Okay I immediately see the problem. `#chat_container` should not be a flexbox. That can drastically change the behaviour. Secondly, remove all CSS where you're trying to hide the scroll bar. You need to put `overflow:hidden` on `#chat_container` and that will completely hide the scrollbar.

Comment: So, delete `flex:1` `display:flex` & one that hides scrollbar, what about `flex-direction, scrollbar-width, scroll-behavior` get rid of these as well?

Comment: Yep, get rid of all that stuff. Break it down to barebones. Only have the stuff you absolutely need (and know what it does) and then build back up once it's working.